# UITableViewController delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a UITableViewController class that I call "MasterViewController".
From within MasterViewController I want to display a tableview that uses a different UITableViewController (not MasterViewController). I am doing this as another tableview is already using MasterViewController as its delegate and datasource.

I have the following logic in a method of MasterViewController;

```
ToTableViewController *toController = [[ToTableViewController alloc] init];
UIView *toView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,250,200)];
//toView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UITableView *toTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,220,180) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

[toTableView setDelegate:toController];
[toTableView setDataSource:toController];

[toView addSubview:toTableView];

[self.view addSubview:toView];

[toTableView reloadData];
```

I want the ToTableViewController to be the delegate and datasource for this new tableview (toTableView).

The problem is that my ToTableViewController cellForRowAtIndexPath method is not being called. In fact, none of the delegate methods are being called.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure your issue is that the `toController` is being released too early. Using ARC (I assume you are too), I played around with it following what you are trying todo.  And I got the same result where the delegate methods appeared NOT to get called. What solved it was to NOT use a local variable for the `toController`. Instead declare it as a member to the MasterViewController class like

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ToTableViewController *toController;
```

then use the variable name `_toController` to refer to it in the code.

EDIT: just to be clear in my first test I had ToTableViewController inherit from a UITableViewController. Since as such I really didn't need that added UITableView you are creating and attaching the delegates too (you could just use the _toController.view directly) SO on this second test I created a ToTableViewController from scratch inheriting from the delegate protocols where the separate UITableView becomes necessary. Just for completeness here is the code that works:

ToTableViewController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ToTableViewController : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

ToTableViewController.m

```
#import "ToTableViewController.h"

@implementation ToTableViewController

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 13;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *str1 = @"Row #";
    cell.textLabel.text = [str1 stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row+1];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

MasterViewController.m (I declare the toController in the .m file as shown but could do so the .h file instead...)

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "ToTableViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) ToTableViewController *toController;

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _toController = [[ToTableViewController alloc] init];
    UIView *toView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,250,200)];
    toView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UITableView *toTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,220,180) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    [toTableView setDelegate:_toController];
    [toTableView setDataSource:_toController];

    [toView addSubview:toTableView];

    [self.view addSubview:toView];
}

@end
```

Comment: jross, Thanks for taking the time to assist me. This seems to be working. Interestingly, I originally had toController declared as a property of MasterViewController and was running into the same issue. I moved it back as you suggested and it is working. Perhaps something had been corrupted during my last session of xCode.  In any event, this has solved my problem. Thanks very much. Tim

Comment: @TDavey, since I've been learning iOS your question interested me since I have been experimenting w/ similar type scenarios.